# Total Permutations: From Letters ABCDEFGH so that E and D are not next to each other.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Here's my approach and wanted to verify if it's correct:

If $|U|$ is the number of total possible permutations and $|A^c|$ is the total permutations containing the strings DE and ED.

Then $|A|$  the to total permutations where E and D are not next to each other is:

$|A|= |U|-|A^c|$

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Using your notation, could you not have x-x-x-x-E-x-x-D, for example?

Comment: You are right. I will include this in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; your solution assumes that $E$ and $D$ are within two spaces of each other. What if the string begins with $E$ and ends with $D$? Furthermore, when you're considering mutually exclusive cases, you add, rather than multiply, so you'd be looking at $6 \times 720$, not $720^6$.

Instead, I would suggest looking at the complement. What if $E$ and $D$ **are** next to each other? It might be in the form $ED$ or $DE$, but you can consider these two letters as an atomic unit that can be permuted into one of $7$ places.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So, it would be the total possible permutations minus when E and D are next to each other?

Comment: I have modified my question accordingly. Let me know if that's what you meant.

Comment: Technically you're looking for strings that contain $ED$ **or** $DE$ (not "and"), but otherwise, this works. On a more general note, it's better to ask a new question (and link to the old question), rather than edit the question so drastically. Now my answer looks out of place!

Comment: Ok I understand. I will follow the appropriate protocol for the next time I ask a question.